# php-fpm выдает ошибку 500 в браузер

Tags: php, php7, php-fpm

Использую Apache2 + php7.2-fpm

Если в php скрипте есть ошибка, то сервер отдает ошибку 500...

Конфиг [`/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`](https://jsfiddle.net/4tygdwn1/)

И в php скрипте есть запись

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Как сделать вывод ошибок в браузер?

Comment: @D-side, простите, забыл про главную часть... Как сделать вывод ошибок в браузер?

Comment: Не надо так делать. Вот совсем не надо. Все ошибки __должны__ записываться в журнал

Comment: @tutankhamun, но, ведь на этапе разработки будет удобнее если это в браузере будут показывать?

Comment: :) Этап разработки - это навсегда. Отучите себя от `display_errors`. Где-нибудь вы обязательно забудете его выключить

Comment: @tutankhamun, а как включить вывод в браузер? уже все перепробовал (что нашел в гугле).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Решил вопрос.

В конфиге /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini

Нужно следующим параметрам выставить такие значения:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

И перезапустить наш php и apache

```
service php7.2-fpm restart
service apache2 restart
```

И у меня заработал вывод ошибок в браузер.

Перед публикацией проекта нужно вернуть параметры как они были!

Для удобства, можно установить Xdebug:

```
apt-get install php7.2-xdebug
```

И опять нужно перезапустить php и Apache

```
service php7.2-fpm restart
service apache2 restart
```

Для включения Xdebug

```
phpdismod xdebug
```

Для выключения Xdebug

```
phpenmod xdebug
```

После включения или выключения xdebug нужно перезагружать php и Apache.